# Can we install suse studio imagewriter in elementary?

Tags: usb-drive

SUSE studio imagewriter is an excellent tool
[a GUI utility for writing raw disk images & hybrid ISOs to USB keys],
with which you can make live memory sticks.
Can we install it in elementary?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly can be installed on elementary OS. I used the instructions from this [linux Mint tutorial](https://yovantoh.blogspot.com/2015/10/installing-suse-imagewriter-on-linux.html) . The only change I had to do was replace the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev` with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

To download the code, you can find the imagewriter repository [here](https://github.com/openSUSE/imagewriter), and click on the green 'Code' button -> Download zip. Extract the archive and open a Terminal window inside the new folder. Run the commands one by one, and enjoy!
[image]

EDIT: Step-by-step commands from tutorial, updated:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-default`
`qmake DEFINES=USEHAL imagewriter.pro`
`qmake DEFINES=USEUDISKS2 imagewriter.pro`
`make`
`sudo make install`

Comment: thanks Vlad, you gave me very clear instructions, now I also know how to install software packages from the github repository !